# cygwin cannot open .sh file

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cygwin

I using cocos2d to create a Android projection.

one of the step is open build_native.sh
by using cygwin. when execute LS command I can see build_native.sh file is exist. but when I
try to open it(just input file name in this dir)  . it tell me command not found.

it's my first time to using cygwin. so I need some one to help:)

Comment: Please provide the command you used to try to execute the script. Remember that you'll need to include the path to the script, even if it's in the current directory. For example, `./build_native.sh`.

Comment: yeah I did. then it show me please define NDK_ROOT.how to do next ?